# How to align Labels and Texts to Left

Tags: java, jface

I am using jface Dialog for displaying some labels and texts. but i am getting all those displayed in the center, which i want to have as left aligned. so how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Example of your code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Text and Label demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/TextandLabeldemo.htm) you find an example how to setup the GridLayout.